# Php include then grab end of current URL and combine them

Tags: php, include

I am trying to include a file based on the current page of a URL the user is on.

The files are stored in /includes/ in all cases and on the same domain.

If the current URL the user is on is for example:

`www.website.com/page/text_i_want.php?info=tree`

```
<?php $url = curPageURL();?><?php include ("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/includes.'/'.$id = substr( $url, strrpos( $url, '/' )+1"  ?>
```

This is what I have but even if that did work, it would't remove a everything after and including the .php and add .txt to the end

I just want to grab text_i_want from the end of the URL (not including the dynamic part) and add .txt to the end so effectively I am including:

```
{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/includes/text_i_want.txt
```

I keep getting an ';' error and syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO with what I have.

**Update**:

```
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/' . basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); ?>
```

That code grabs the file name at the end of the URL, which is what I want. I am just unsure how to replace .php with .txt

Comment: If you figured out how to solve, I think you should write a answer about it and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @SamOwl Already have :) Not allowed to accept your own answer for 2 days though.

Comment: no problem! Stack Overflow limitations... ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:** (But unsure how efficient or neat this is, but it works)

I didn't really know what I was doing but somehow I've managed to mix together @SamOwl's code and one I found and edit them slightly to achieve the result In wanted:

```
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/' . basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'php?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) . 'txt'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/' . basename(__FILE__, '.php') . '.txt'; ?>
```

UPDATE

According to your update, try `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` PHP Docs says: "The URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance, '/index.html'".

If this is not what you want, give a read on [PHP Server Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: you'll need to prepend `{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/includes/` because you will get only `text_i_want.txt`

Comment: Thank you @SamOwl unfortunately it doesn't achieve what I was trying for. That adds the file name of the code you have written into the include, which is different from the file name one in the URL. As the file I am adding your code to is within an include of it's own, and that included file name is appearing as the file name. Not 'text_i_want' from the URL of the current page.

It needs to be the file displayed at the end of the URL, not file the code is in.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what you really need. Can you edit your question to explain this better?

Comment: @SamOwl Sorry I am finding it a little difficult to explain, I edited my question to add more detail :) basically text_i_want.php is made up from many includes and this code gets the root file name, not the one visible in the browser address bar.

Comment: @GoldenGonaz Did you mean that your http server rewrites the file name? Because i don't see another way of the file name be different to the url file name. (if there is another, comment please).

Comment: @SamOwl - I made another update to my original post. The method you supplied doesn't work if the code itself is included into the main page. It will not get the file name of the main page URL, it instead gets the file name of the included file.